# UIScrollView with reusable items

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

Due to a very misfortunate obstacle I have no means of using UITableView and are stuck with UIScrollView. The reason is that the items frames are dynamic and there should be no space between them. So for instance I get 10 items, 8 of them can be on the left side and 2 very large one on the right side. All the items are build up depending on a network content like images or videos.

So my question is how to efficiently and as much seamlessly as possible unload items from the memory and load them back in? Which scroll view delegate methods should I look into?

Also, my scroll view has no pagination and it's not applicable. There can be something like 20 items or 2 items on screen at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eugene, there was an excellent presentation at WWDC last year about advanced UIScrollView techniques. It can be found here:  https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/advanced-scrollview-techniques.html#advanced-scrollview-techniques

I believe it will answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I'll look into it and will post if it helped

Comment: The techniques described in there is similar to what I need. Thank you